# How to pass variable in fetch mail template from database?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer with a template stored in a database. How do I pass a variable and then fetch the HTML template from the database?

```
$link = "click.php?username=" . $userid;
$subject = $template["subject"];
$message = $template["message"];
```

How do I pass `$link` in `$message`?

Comment: Can you add some more information what you have tried till now? Any error messges? What kind of data is stored in `$template["message"]` and do you want to pass the contentn of `$link` to a special position in the message?

Comment: $template is a array fetch from database and $template["message"] has a content like example $template["message"]="<p>$link<p>" right but its not pass as it is show in my send mail

Comment: And you want to add the content of the variable `$link` to `$template["message"]`, right?

Comment: Do you want to append $link to $template? If so try $template["message"] .= $link;

Comment: May be do something different. use str_replace or preg_replace to replace the occurrence of $link in $message by its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

```
$link = "click.php?username=" . $userid;
$template["message"] .= "<p>".$link."</p>"; 
$subject = $template["subject"];
$message = $template["message"];
```

**for your understanding:** you have to add the content stored in `$link` to the content (if there is some) of `$template["message"]` therefore `.=` in line 2.

**Note:** `$template["message"]` has to be a string (which it seems to be related to your sample) and the content of `$link` will be added at the end of all content which might already be existing in `$template["message"]`